# How to setup your DNS to send mail on behalf of your other domain from your mailserver

Tags: dns, postfix-mta, mail-server, spf, dkim

I created my own mailserver using postfix.
The mailserver is able to send mail from my domain.
Now I want to send mail for my other domain user in "FROM"
doing so, my mail ends up in spam

I have set my spf and dkim record for my mailserver domain.

Please guide me how to do it correctly...?

Comment: What do you mean other domain users? Another user of the same domain or a different domain altogether? I don't think your question needed to be downvoted, I think it can be made more clear and it's a good question.

Comment: other domain here means that if I have my mailserver setup is on example1.com and I wanted to send mail using my mailserver FROM user@example2.com it gets spammed, while if I send mail FROM user@example1.com it reaches the inbox.

Comment: Is there anything different about the headers of emails from one vs. the other? You may want to look at them directly but also run them through a tool like mxtoolbox’s header analyzer.

Comment: And is email authentication (SPF, DKIM, and ideally DMARC) set up for both? Are example2.com and example1.com have similar histories (that is, example2 wasn't used to send out some spam or anything?) and are you using the same email host for both? Check email auth right away as maybe you've not yet implemented it for example2?

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me. Did you register the domain example2.com recently? Since a lot of spam's sent with newer domain names, it can count against you a bit in terms of deliverability.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but the thing is that I want to create something like sendgrid, and Sendgrid can send mail for any domain, How do they do it? How will I have to do it?

Comment: Also I have set every Record like SPF and DKIM for my example1 which is my mailserver domain. Also sending mail using this mailserver FROM user@example1.com reaches in users inbox.

Comment: How they do it depends on whether you have a dedicated IP and your own authentication set up or not. The sort of sending you’re talking about is where the return path domain is sendgrid’s and they authenticate that not your domain. They really get the details right with this. Why not authenticate for each domain separately for greater control? Anyway, I’m sorry I wasn’t able to offer you any useful insight.

Comment: Why do you want to create something like sendgrid? Are you trying to start an ESP?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wanted to build something like sendgrid. sendgrid sends mail on behalf of any domain and that reaches the inbox, while it shows "via sendgrid.net" if the domain is not verified with sendgrid.

Comment: So my basic question is how to send mail from your mailserver having any domain in your FROM so that it reaches inbox and shows "via example1.com"